# SSRS How to display only one row in groups column

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, bids

I'm making a RS but I can't find on how to display only one cell for the group column.

The upper report is what I'm making and I want my report to be look like the bottom report

[![The upper report is what I'm making and I want my report to be look like the 
bottom report][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIjgj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIjgj.png)

Also is there a way to edit the report again. I mean to display the Report Wizard again and assign if either the column is gonna be `page,groups or details`

Edit 1:

I tried deleting the columns and adding group manually. But the output is wrong
The column `[Agent Name]` is the only drillable column, you can refer to the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delete all the groups/rows except the bottom (details row), then add the groups back, but when adding them select the 'Add Group Header' checkbox - This will create the merged cells...

Alternatively, select the cells you want merged (with control+click), then right click one and merge them

After manually creating the row group. You have to go to row group properties>Visibility>Select the 'hide'>Check the 'Display can be toggled by this report item:' and select the column group.

Comment: no I want the groups but when you take alook at my project (UPPER) my `[CSP]` column is not merged unlike the one in the bottom it is merged

Comment: I want it to be merged.

Comment: Do I have to remove the rowgroups at the bottom window?

Comment: Right click them and select Remove Group:?

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for SQL 2013.

Comment: ahh.. sorry thats before my time. Consider upgrading? haha

Comment: right now I can't. Ill get back to you coz I cant continue the project now.

Comment: I tried your answer. Although its almost correct. There are some issues. The column `[Agent Name]` is the only drillable column